# ArgumentOutOfRange error after List.Clear()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After first script complication, when that block fire

```
 if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)
                {
                    achiveList.Clear();

                    currentAchive = 0;

                    noOneInWaitLine = true;
                }
```

I got `ArgumentOutOfRange` error  in that line

```
newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];
```

And really don't understand how I can get rid of that error

There my script (its run in `Update()`)

```
void WaitLine()
    {

        if (achiveList!=null&& achiveList.Count !=0 && noOneInWaitLine == false)
        {
            Debug.Log(achiveList.Count);
            newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];

            if (showFinished == true)
            {


                if (curTime == 0)
                {
                    curTime = Time.time; // Pause 
                }
                if ((Time.time - curTime) >= 3f && achiveList.Count != currentAchive)
                {
                    currentAchive++;
                    curTime = 0;
                    Debug.Log("Timer Finished");
                    showFinished = false;

                }

            }
            else
            {
                ShowAchiv(newAchiveNumber);
                showFinished = true;
                if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)
                {
                    achiveList.Clear();

                    currentAchive = 0;

                    noOneInWaitLine = true;
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are accessing element at index 0 after clearing the list. There are no elements in the list and so there is no element at position 0. That is why you are receiving the exception back. I suppose that there is a problem with your logic - how comes that you are trying to read a value from the list after clearing it? That scenario should never happen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no sscce

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)` to check when you are reading the last value in currentAchive . If this is true then the last value in the List is `achiveList.Count-1` because array/list starts from 0.

So, change `if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)` to `if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count-1)`.

Also, before you do `newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];`
, you have to check if `currentAchive` is > `achiveList.Count-1`. If this is true then don't do `newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];`.

So, wrap that around if statement:

```
if (currentAchive > achiveList.Count-1)
{
    //Finshed reading array exit?
}else
{
    newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];
}
```

The whole code should look like something below. You may have to to modify it a little bit since to accommodate your game logic since I have no idea what other code in that function do.

```
void WaitLine()
{
    if (achiveList != null && achiveList.Count != 0 && noOneInWaitLine == false)
    {
        Debug.Log(achiveList.Count);

        if (currentAchive > achiveList.Count-1)
        {
            //Finshed reading array exit?
        }else
        {
            newAchiveNumber = achiveList[currentAchive];
        }

        if (showFinished == true)
        {
            if (curTime == 0)
            {
                curTime = Time.time; // Pause 
            }
            if ((Time.time - curTime) >= 3f && achiveList.Count != currentAchive)
            {
                currentAchive++;
                curTime = 0;
                Debug.Log("Timer Finished");
                showFinished = false;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            ShowAchiv(newAchiveNumber);
            showFinished = true;
            if (currentAchive == achiveList.Count)
            {
                achiveList.Clear();

                currentAchive = 0;

                noOneInWaitLine = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , error dont show any more. Bur another problem has arisen? after i refill list with new values- script just dont work. no error but no work either i guess its got trapped in  if (currentAchive > achiveList.Count-1)
        {

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, I have no idea what you are doing or what you intend this code to do because you didn't mention that in your answer. The goal if this answer if to fix your error message or at-least to show you how to fix out of range error.

Comment: You help me immensely, thank you a lot. I find where was problem ( noOneInWaitLine = true - status was define incoorrectly by myself) and it looks like all working now, cause you figuread out main error (ArgumentOutOfRange) Thank you again.